# Table that lists things lost during a join (SQL or Pandas)?

Tags: python, mysql, join

I am comparing two tables and performing a join on a column of strings.  However, I would like to also create a table that shows me any rows that are lost in the join because the match is not valid. See example below.

```
Input:
Table 1                     Table 2
  A     B     C                  A      B    C
'..'   '..'  'c'               '..'   '..'  'c'
'..'   '..'  'd'               '..'   '..'  'd'
'..'   '..'  'e'               '..'   '..'  'f'
```

Then after joining on column C, the resulting table of non-matches would look like

```
Output:
A      B     C
'..' '..' 'e/f'
```

I don't really care if it's e or f that is in the resulting table. I just need one of them.

Does anyone know the SQL/Python (Pandas) code that could accomplish this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With SQL you can use a left outer join. This will give you all of the records in Table 1 and only those in Table 2 that match, so the records in Table 1 that have no match will have NULL for column C in the corresponding Table 2.

```
SELECT t1.* FROM `Table 1` t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN `Table 2` t2
ON t1.C = t2.C 
WHERE t2.C IS NULL;
```

For your example, this should give:

```
A      B     C
'..' '..'   'e'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3], 'B': [4,5,6], 'C': ['c', 'd', 'e']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3], 'b': [4,5,6], 'C': ['c', 'd', 'f']})

df1.merge(df2, how='left', on='C')
   A  B  C   a   b
0  1  4  c   1   4
1  2  5  d   2   5
2  3  6  e NaN NaN
```

Because you are merging on column `C`, any value from column `C` of `df2` that is not in column `C` of `df1` will not be in the left merged group.

You can use the tilda (`~`) negation operator and do a boolean filter.

```
>>> df2[~df2.C.isin(df1.C)]
   C  a  b
2  f  3  6
```